# If a continuous path $\Xi$ in $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ starts and end on $\partial(A)$, show that $A-\Xi$ is disconnected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

If a continuous path $\Xi$ in a closed and bounded subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ starts and end on $\partial(A)$, show that $A-\Xi$ is disconnected

To make things formal let $T=[0,1]$ and say that $\Xi$ is a pair of continuous functions $x \colon T \to \mathbb{R}$,$y \colon T \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$\forall\,t\;(x(t),y(t))\in A$

$(x(0),y(0))\in \partial A$

$(x(1),y(1))\in \partial A$

$\exists\;t\;s.t.\;(x(t),y(t))\in int(A)$.

Show that $A-\Xi$ is disconnected. This is obvious from any illustration, but finding a rigorous proof eludes me. If instead we are working in the unit square for example and the path $\Xi$ is instead the graph of a continuous function $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ then I can do it.

Define the sets $U=${$(x,y):f(x)>y$}$,\;L= ${$(x,y):f(x)<y$}$ $ U and L are open because f is continuous. They are both nonempty because the graph of f has a point in the interior. and they obviously partition the space $[0,1]^2-\Xi$ so we are done.

any help or references in the general case would be heavily appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't $A$ need to be simply connected?

Comment: I was thinking that I don't need any connectedness properties because if I start with a disconnected space then I will end with a disconnected space if I only remove a path. I may be not understanding your question. Do you have a counter-example where $A$ is not simply connected? If so, I would love to hear it. But the application I have in mind is to the unit square, so if adding simply connected helps, by all means.

Comment: Yeah, if A is an annulus then a path that cuts from the edge to the inner circle will leave A connected.

Comment: You're right I see what you're saying, the answer below clarified this as well. Yes simply connected. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Use the riemann mapping theorem. It implies in particular that any closed, bounded and simply connected subset of $R^2$ is homeomorphic to the standart 2-disc. Thus the problem reduces to the much simpler scenario when $A$ is the 2 disc and $\gamma$ is a properly embedded path.

Comment: Together with an arc $\alpha$ on $\partial A$, $\gamma$ will then form a jordan curve $g$, embedded in $\mathbb R^2$. The jordan curve theorem now implies that $g$ separates $\mathbb R^2$ into two components, one of which is the region bounded by $g$. One can now easily see that this region must lie in $A$ and is not all of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region also needs to be simply connected (otherwise take an annulus).

I don't know any references but I think you could get a nice proof in general if you don't mind using the Jordan Curve theorem:

Suppose your curve intersects the boundary at the points $p_1, p_2$ and construct a closed curve consisting of the arc of the boundary (since the boundary is homeomorphic to $S^1$) between $p_1$ and $p_2$ and the interior curve.

Comment: Nice! This is exactly what I wanted. Can we simply deal with the space filling curve problem above by assuming that the $A-\Xi$ is non-empty. Also to apply the jordan curve theorem we need that the path does not intersect itself. But it seems like this will be true even if the curve intersects itself.

Comment: Incidentally if the curve does not intersect itself it cannot be space filling

Comment: And if its space filling the complement (in $A$) will be empty.

Comment: My answer shows that even for simply connected regions, the claim is false if we do not assume something like "no (or isolated) self intersections".

Answer (score 4):

This fails if $A = \{(x,y) \bigm| 1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 4\}$, using $\Xi = [1,2] \times \{0\}$.

Comment: You're right we need simply connected. Like the comment above says. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is true. Take $A = [0,1]\times [0,2]$ and let $(x,y) : T \to [0,1]^2$ be surjective, i.e.a **space filling curve**, which we can easily take to start and end in $(0,0) \in \partial A$.

In this case, $A \setminus \Xi = [0,1]\times (1,2]$ is connected.

Comment: You're right thank you, can we deal with this problem by assuming the curve crosses itself only a countable number of times?

Comment: Thanks I think that that would imply that it cannot be space filling. But I never assumed that the size of the intersection was 2, the last assumption says there exists not for every.

Comment: I correct myself. I misread one of your assumptions.

Comment: What will certainly help is if you assume that the self-intersection points are *isolated*, i.e, form a discrete subset of $A$.